# How to exclude path from spring-security basic auth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using basic authentication with `spring-security` (`security.basic.enabled=true`), and want to exclude a certain path and all sub-paths.

The following does not work:

```
@Configuration
public class WildcardConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        //allow anonymous access to all sub paths
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/my/**").permitAll();
    }
}

@RestController
public class SubController {
    @GetMapping("/my/sub/{id}")
    public String test(@PathVariable id) {
        return "got: " + id;
    }
}
```

When I call `localhost:8080/my/sub/123`.

Result: 401 not authorized.

Why?

Comment: Is that your only configuration or do you have more configurations? And do you send any `Authentication` header in your request? And don't call `super.configure(http);`, it overrides your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/my/**");
}
```